# ScrollView doesn't work with ConstraintLayout inside Fragment

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-scrollview, android-constraintlayout

I have a ScrollView and a ConstraintLayout with some views inside, but it is not scrolling. I saw in other related questions some advice to add:

```
android:fillViewport="true"
```

to the layout and I ever tried with NestedScrollView and change the position of ScrollView, but nothing helps.

My fragment layout is:

```
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    >

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"

        android:id="@+id/layout_style"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:paddingEnd="?attr/listPreferredItemPaddingRight"
        android:paddingStart="?attr/listPreferredItemPaddingLeft"
        android:paddingTop="?attr/listPreferredItemPaddingLeft"


        >


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lbl_style"
            style="@style/HeadSection"
            android:text="@string/label_style"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline_label_margins"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txt_beer_description"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lbl_short_style"
            style="@style/Label"
            android:text="@string/label_short_style"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline_label_margins"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/lbl_style_name"/>

        <TextView

            android:id="@+id/txt_short_style"
            style="@style/Content"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline_content_margins"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txt_style_name"
            tools:text="American Dark Lager"/>


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lbl_style_name"
            style="@style/Label"
            android:text="@string/label_style_name"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline_label_margins"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/lbl_style"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_style_name"
            style="@style/Content"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline_content_margins"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/lbl_style"
            tools:text="American-Style Dark Lager"/>


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lbl_style_category_name"
            style="@style/Label"
            android:layout_height="19dp"
            android:text="@string/label_style_category_name"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline_label_margins"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/lbl_short_style"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_style_category_name"
            style="@style/Content"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline_content_margins"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txt_short_style"
            tools:text="North American Lager"/>


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lbl_beer"
            style="@style/HeadSection"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:text="@string/label_detail_head_beer_info"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lbl_beer_name"
            style="@style/Label"
            android:text="@string/label_detail_beer_name"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline_label_margins"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/lbl_beer"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_beer_name"
            style="@style/Content"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline_content_margins"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/lbl_beer"
            tools:text="Heineken"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lbl_beer_Description"
            style="@style/Label"
            android:text="@string/label_detail_beer_description"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline_label_margins"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/lbl_beer_name"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_beer_description"
            style="@style/Content"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline_content_margins"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/lbl_beer_Description"/>


        <android.support.constraint.Guideline
            android:id="@+id/guideline_label_margins"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_constraintGuide_begin="16dp"/>

        <android.support.constraint.Guideline
            android:id="@+id/guideline_content_margins"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_constraintGuide_begin="120dp"/>


    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

This layout is inflated in a fragment that is:

content_detail.xml:

```
<fragment
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_detail"

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"

    />
```

And the root layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/layout_detail"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/card_height_huge"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        >

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            >

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                />


            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"

                />
        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


    <include
        layout="@layout/content_detail"/>


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

-- EDIT

there is a [bug report](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37115702) about this behavior.

I found a bug that was supposed to be fixed, but some others users related still report the issue:

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37115702

-- EDIT

I rotate the phone, the `txt_beer_description` TextView goes off the screen. So if I scroll the scroll works until the end of txt_beer_description, no more.

-- EDIT

style file is:

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@android:color/black</item>


    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>


    <style name="SearchBeerItemBaseText">
        <item name="android:gravity">start|center_vertical</item>
        <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:layout_marginStart">8dp</item>
    </style>

    <style name="SearchBeerItemTextPrimary" parent="SearchBeerItemBaseText">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/primary_text</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">16sp</item>
    </style>

    <style name="SearchBeerItemTextSecundary" parent="SearchBeerItemBaseText">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/secondary_text</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">14sp</item>
    </style>

    <style name="CollectionItemBaseText">
        <item name="android:gravity">start|center_vertical</item>
        <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    </style>


    <style name="CollectionItemTextPrimary" parent="CollectionItemBaseText">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">15sp</item>
        <item name="android:focusable">false</item>
        <item name="android:focusableInTouchMode">false</item>
        <item name="android:clickable">false</item>

    </style>

    <style name="CollectionItemTextSecundary" parent="CollectionItemBaseText">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">13sp</item>
    </style>


    <style name="SearchActivityPrimaryImage">
        <item name="android:layout_width">56dp</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">56dp</item>
    </style>

    <style name="HeadSection">
        <item name="android:layout_marginTop">16dp</item>
        <item name="android:layout_marginBottom">8dp</item>
        <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>

        <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/primary</item>
        <item name="android:textAppearance">@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Subhead</item>
    </style>

    <style name="Label">
        <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
        <item name="android:layout_marginTop">16dp</item>
        <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/primary_text</item>
        <item name="android:textAppearance">@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1</item>
    </style>

    <style name="Content" >
        <item name="android:layout_marginTop">16dp</item>
        <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/secondary_text</item>
        <item name="android:textAppearance">@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1</item>

    </style>


    <style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"/>

    <style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>




</resources>
```

Comment: see this http://tools.android.com/recent/androidstudio22preview2available

Comment: "ConstraintLayout now works properly inside ScrollView"

Answer (score 1):

In your `ScorllView`, change layout_height to:
`android:layout_height="wrap_content"`

Comment: @alexpfx Can you wrap the whole fragment layout, may be in a FrameLayout (with layout_height = match parent)? There is 1 document regarding this, will try to find out. Btw, I can't simulate your in my android studio, as i don't have your Style :)

Comment: I think I tried this way too but I wilk check when I get home. I think problem may be related to these Guidelines, but i'm not sure

Answer (score 1):

The problem is related with the appbar:

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/card_height_huge"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        />
```

I shouldn't use app:layout_behavior in that.